# Inverting a spherical harmonic expansion

Tags: entropy, spherical-harmonics

I am referring to [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9303048) paper by Srednicki, page 4, equations 14-17. Equation 14 is a Hamiltonian, which is to be written as $H = \sum_{lm} H_{lm}$. The $H_{lm}$ are given in equation (17).I am trying to derive equation (17). In order to do this, Srednicki introduces the following partial wave operators:

$$\varphi_{lm}(x) = x \int d\Omega Z_{lm}(\theta, \phi) \varphi(\vec{x}), $$
and
$$\pi_{lm}(x) = x \int d\Omega Z_{lm}(\theta, \phi) \pi(\vec{x}). $$

Here, $x = \lvert \vec{x} \rvert$, $d\Omega = \sin \theta d\theta d\phi$ and the $Z_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ are real spherical harmonics.They are also orthonormal and complete. I figured that since equation (17) is in terms of $\varphi_{lm}$ and $\pi_{lm}$,one way to prove equation (17), would be to invert the above relations and make $\varphi_{lm}$ the subject:

$$\int d\Omega' Z_{l'm'}(\theta',\phi') \varphi_{lm} = \int d\Omega d\Omega' x Z_{lm}(\theta, \phi) Z_{l'm'}(\theta', \phi')\varphi(\vec{x}) $$

I tried to evaluate the integral on the RHS by using the orthonormality of the $Z_{lm}$ but that only seems to work when the arguments of the function are the same. Could integrating with respect to $\Omega'$ yield factors of $\delta(\theta-\theta') \delta(\phi-\phi')$?

Is there a more efficient way to derive equations (17) from (14), (15), and (16)? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The LHS of your expressions do not depend on the angles: $\phi_{lm}$ depends only on the radial coordinate $r$.
You need to use completeness rather than orthogonality:
$$
\sum_{l,m} Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi) Y^*_{lm}(\theta',\phi') = \delta(\phi-\phi')\delta(\cos\theta-\cos\theta')
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_{lm}Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi) \phi_{lm}(r) = \phi(\theta, \phi,r)\equiv \phi(x).
$$